# Visual Studio 2015 Community + Resharper 9: 2 pop-up lists show for intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, autocomplete, resharper, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and Resharper 9.
In XAML Editor, when typing some element, two pop-up lists of intellisense shown up, one of VS Intellisense, the other one is from Resharper.

[image: Two pop-up menu of Intellisense]

Could anybody help me with this problem? Thank you!

**ReSharper version info**

[image: ReSharper version info]

**Visual Studio version info**

[image]

Comment: Log a bug with the ReSharper team. Does not happen with VS 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: What exact version of R# do you use (ReSharper | Help | About JetBrains R#)?

Comment: I already updated the exact version of R# and VS. I hope that it can help.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a change in Visual Studio - the XAML editor was replaced/updated and got a new GUID, which your version of ReSharper doesn't recognise. So, it doesn't know to block Visual Studio's code completion, but still knows it's a XAML file, so shows its own, and you end up with two code completion windows.

The easiest fix is to update to the latest version of ReSharper, which has fixed this. Alternatively, you can try and disable Visual Studio's code completion for XAML in Tools → Options → Text Editor, or disable ReSharper's code completion for XAML in ReSharper → Options → Intellisense.